# d3js: Replace a particular tick value on X-Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axes

I have a bubble chart which looks like the following:

[image]

The data that I am using has the following format:

```
 var data = [{name: "A", rank: 1, student_percentile: 100.0, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "B", rank: 45, student_percentile: 40.3, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "C", rank: 89, student_percentile: 89.7, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "D", rank: 23, student_percentile: 10.9, 
         admit_probability: 24},
        {name: "E", rank: 56, student_percentile: 30.3, 
         admit_probability: 24},
         {name: "F", rank: 34, student_percentile: 110, 
         admit_probability: 84}];
```

For some values in input, I don't have correct percentile value, so I am putting by default 110. Now, I want to plot these values and on X-axis instead of 110, I want to show "NAN". For example, Here "F" has X-axis value as 110. So, I want to mark that value as "NAN".

How can I replace a value on X-axis?

My script is as follows:

```
var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(
                d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.student_percentile; })
            )
        .nice() 
        .range([0, width]);

    var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.rank; }))
        .nice()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tickFormat` to change that specific value:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d === 110 ? "NAN" : d
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 110])
  .range([20, 480]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d === 110 ? "NAN" : d
  })

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: I am facing one issue. As X-axis scale is dynamically chosen based on input data, as difference in values became smaller (90, 95, 100, 105, 110), I am getting 2 separate values for "NAN". 
I changed the line to: 
tickFormat(function(d) {
     return d > 100 ? "NAN" : d
 }
I just want anything above 100 to be "NAN" but only one such tick mark.

Comment: @Yesha since this is a different problem, I suggest you posting a new question, explaining exactly your values and, preferably, with a [MCVE] showing the axis. Have in mind that you have a different question here: ticks are automatically created by the axis, but you want to show only 1 tick (regardless it being a number or a string).